# BitTorrent p2p - What to do with very large blocks of data, read from piece message from a peer (larger than piece-length)?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, torrent

I am writing a BitTorrent client, where the application is receiving **large blocks of data** after **requesting pieces** from other peers. Sometimes the blocks are **larger than piece-length** of the torrent.

For example, where torrent piece-length *524288 bytes*, some piece requests result in *1940718596 bytes* long responses.

Also, the message seems **valid** as the length encoded in the first four bytes happens to be the same (that large num).

**Question:** What to do with that data, should I **ignore the excess bytes** (after piece-length)? Or, should I **write the data into corresponding files**? - what is concerning because it might *override the next pieces*!

Comment: keep in mind that numbers in the peer wire protocol are big endian.

Answer (score 1):

The largest chunk of a piece the protocol allows in a *piece* message is 16 KB (16384 bytes). So if a peer sent a 1940718596 bytes (1.8 GB) long *piece* message, the correct response is to **disconnect** from it.

Also, if a peer sends a *piece* message that doesn't correspond to a *request* message you have sent earlier, you shall also **disconnect** from it.

A peer that receives a *request* message asking for more than a 16 KB chunk, shall also **disconnect** the requester. Requesting a whole piece in a single *request* message is NOT allowed.

A *request* message that goes outside the end of the piece, is of course, also NOT allowed.

---

While it's possible that you will encounter other peers that don't follow the protocol, the most likely when writing a new client, is that the error is on your side.

The most important tool you can use is **WireShark**. Look how other clients behave and compare with yours.